# Counting Alpha Chars in Array

Tags: c++

I am trying to count how many values in the array `wrongLetters` are actually letters. I have developed the below structure to do this, but it does not produce the correct values. It appears that the loop is double counting, as the value of used begins to increase exponentially when ran in my full program. Any recommendations on a better way to do this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (wrongLetters[i] != 0)
            used += 1;               // used counts how many alpha chars are in the array
    }
```

Comment: what is `wrongLetters` and how do you fill it?

Comment: Did you mean to check using `std::isalpha(wrongLetters[i])`?

Comment: the general way to determine if you have a letter is [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha)

Comment: the code you show here increases `used` linearly at most

Comment: I'm assuming `wrongLetters` contains all 26 letters of the alphabet, given that the loop goes up to 26 (exclusive) from 0? Given this, it seems more like a logical error, and you might need to provide more code

Comment: It very well could be a logical error, but I was trying to spare everybody the pain of sifting through my long and less-than perfect code. I will edit my question and post the entire code then.

Comment: @KnightValor If anything provide a [MCVE], instead of dumping your whole code. That's not useful! Rolled back.

Comment: @KnightValor If the issue is merely figuring out how many alphabetic characters in a string, is it necessary to post an entire program, ASCII graphics and all?  Why not a simple function that takes a string and returns an int that denotes the count, and then post your attempt at it.

Comment: @KnightValor Taking into account the name of the array it contains none valid letter.:)

Comment: After further examining my code, the problem is not with actually identifying whether or not an array element actually is a char. The problem is that any letters that get added to the array as the program runs are then re-counted, which is why it appears the value of used is increasing exponentially. How can I add additional functionality that can also check to see if the letter already is in the array?

Comment: @KnightValor -- Use a `std::set<char>` instead of an array as it does not store duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to count how many values in the array `wrongLetters` are actually letters.

Supposed you have something like

```
std::string wrongLetters;

// input at wrongLetters
```

You can count the *alpha chars* like this

```
size_t alphaChars = 0;
for(auto c : wrongLetters) { 
    if(std::isalpha(c)) ++alphaChars;
}
```

Comment: Which is what `std::count_if` does.

Comment: I mean, it's really one more line onto your answer. The core content is already there.

Answer (score 0):

To count the alpha characters you could do this:

Assuming `wrongletters` is an array container

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < wrongletters.size(); i++)
    if(std::isalpha(wrongletters[i]))
        count++;
```

Now for your code, maybe you needed to check `wrongletters[i] != '0'` which will check for zero the `character` and not the `integer`.